# Understanding a claim -- which interpretation is right?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I'm trying to disprove the following claim.

> If $A$, as a subspace of $X$, has discrete topology, then $X$ has discrete topology.

The statement `If A, as a subspace of X, has discrete topology` means all of the subsets of $A$ are open sets in the metric space $(X,d)$ not $(A,d)$, right?

Or does it just mean that $(A,d)$ is a subspace of $(X,d)$ and A has discrete topology --- all subsets of $A$ are open sets in the metric space $(A,d)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the clause $A$ as a subspace of $X$, means that we consider $(A,d)$ (in the metric case) as a space in its own right, and the fact that this has the discrete topology, means that every point $a$ of $A$ has a ball $B(a,r)$ such that the ball in $A$ is just the singleton set $\{a\}$. So the only point of $A$ that has distance less than $r$ to $a$ is $a$ itself.

E.g. consider $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{R}$, usual metric. Then the ball in $\mathbb{Z}$ of radius $1$ around any point of $\mathbb{Z}$ is just that point (although there are many points of the whole space within that distance, there are none other from $\mathbb{Z}$).

Comment: Thank you very much. I just wanted to know whether if we should consider $(A,d)$ "as a space in its own right" --- hence if A has discrete topology then all elements of $2^A$ are open sets in the metric space $(A,d)$.

Comment: @Adeeb and this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

There is a counter example for this.

Consider $X=(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{T} )$, where $\mathbb{T}$ is the half-open interval topology in $\mathbb{R}$. Let $Y=X\times X$ with the product topology and $S=\left\{ (x,-x) : x\in X \right\}$ the antidiagonal.

For $(x,y)\in S$, consider the open set in Y given by $[x,+\infty)\times [y,+\infty)=A$. Thus, the intersection $S\cap A=\left\{ (x,y)\right\}$. This means that the product topology in $S$ is the discrete topology; since $Y$ does not have the discrete topology, your claim is false.

Comment: My counter-example was X=$(\mathbb{R},d_E)$ and $A=(${1,2}$,d_E)$